# Google Cloud Platform - Catch and log errors and automatically terminate VM

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, stderr, terminate, stackdriver

I am running a workflow on a n1-ultramem-40 instance that will run for several days. If an error occurs, I would like to catch and log the error, be notified, and automatically terminate the Virtual Machine. Could I use StackDriver and gcloud logging to achieve this? How could I automatically terminate the VM using these tools? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's break the puzzle into two parts.  The first is logging an error to Stackdriver and the second is performing an external action automatically when such an error is detected.

Stackdriver provides a wide variety of language bindings and package integrations that result in log messages being written.  You could include such API calls in your application which detects the error.  If you don't have access to the source code of your application but it instead logs to an external file, you could use the Stackdriver agents to monitor log files and relay the log messages to Stackdriver.

Once you have the error messages being sent to Stackdriver, the next task would be defining a Stackdriver log export definition.  This is the act of defining a "filter" that looks for the specific log entry message(s) that you are interested in acting upon.  Associated with this export definition and filter would be a PubSub topic.  A pubsub message would then be written to this topic when an Stackdriver log entry is made.

Finally, we now have our trigger to perform your action.  We could use a Cloud Function triggered from a PubSub message to execute arbitrary API logic.  This could be code that performs an API request to GCP to terminate the VM.

Comment: Thanks Kolban. I'll give this a go!

Comment: I like kolban@ answer. A more direct way to trigger the VM's delete would be for your code to trigger the demise of its VM instance directly. See davidstanke's self-destructing VM sample (https://github.com/davidstanke/samples/tree/master/self-destructing-vm). The simplest solution would be to have your code exit back into the startup script that ends with the `gcloud delete ...` step.